# align-content: space-between не работает, flex

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Не могу понять, что не так? Хочу, чтобы "b" прижимался к низу, а "a" оставался наверху. Подскажите

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: space-between;
  background: #ffc;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background: #f66;
}

.b {
  background: #99f;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <div class='a'>123</div>
  <div class='b'>456</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Точняк! Спасибо! Сделай это ответом, я отмечу как правильный ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прописывая `flex-direction: column`, вы меняете направление оси, следовательно для вертикального выравнивания следует использовать уже не `align-items`, а `justify-content`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что надо использовать `justify-content`. А `align-content` относится к поперечной оси. Так как у вас ось вертикальная, то `align-content` относится к выравниванию по горизонтали.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ffc;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background: #f66;
}

.b {
  background: #99f;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex'>
  <div class='a'>123</div>
  <div class='b'>456</div>
</div>
```